# Python/Pandas find closest value above/below in one Column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, astronomy

I have a large data frame (~1 million rows). I am ultimately going to be interpolating spectra between two age groups. However I need to first find the nearest values above and below any age I need to find.

The DataFrame briefly looks like this

```
 Age   Wavelength   Luminosity
 1     
 1
 1
 4
 4
 6
 6
```

I need to be able to input 5, and return values 4 and 6. I am struggling to find  a way to do this? This is what I tried :

```
def findnearest(array,value):
    idx = np.searchsorted(array,value, side='left')
    if idx > 125893.0:
        return array[idx]
    else:
        return array[idx]
    idx1 = np.searchsorted(array,value, side='right')
    if idx1 < 2e10:
        return array[idx1]
    else:
        return array [idx1-1]

C = findnearest(m05_010['age'], 5.12e7)

print(C)
```

This only returns one value, and not both. Is this the right path or should I be doing something different? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `bisect`, its a lot faster and is made for this purpose only.

```
from bisect import *
arr = np.array([1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6])

value = 5
lower = arr[bisect_left(arr, value) - 1]
above = arr[bisect_right(arr, value)]
lower, above
```

Output -

```
(4, 6)
```

Heres the time comparison from Ipython -

```
%timeit for x in range(100): arr[bisect_left(arr, value)]
```

Output -

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 92.4 µs per loop

And using `searchsorted` -

```
%timeit for x in range(100): arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'left')-1]
```

Output -

> The slowest run took 7.62 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 10000 loops, best of
>   3: 142 µs per loop

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Comment: @hashcode55 tried bisect method but not working for array    `array = np.array([6.379155435759211, 5.952380952380958, 6.805929919137463 ,3.8634321653189487,
 2.20125786163521, -0.314465408805071, -1.976639712488791, 8.04132973944295,
 10.55705300988321, 12.21922731356695, 14.734950584007205, 3.548966756513936,
 3.796046720575037])` it is returning `(-1.976639712488791, 8.04132973944295)` regardless of the value thats passed in. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC and assuming sorted input array, you can do something like this -

```
above = arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'left')-1]
below = arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'right')]
```

Sample runs -

Case 1: Without exact match for value

```
In [17]: arr = np.array([1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6])

In [18]: value = 5

In [19]: above = arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'left')-1]
    ...: below = arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'right')]
    ...: 

In [20]: above, below
Out[20]: (4, 6)
```

Case 2: With exact match for value

```
In [33]: arr = np.array([1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6])

In [34]: value = 5

In [35]: above = arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'left')-1]
    ...: below = arr[np.searchsorted(arr,value,'right')]
    ...: 

In [36]: above, below
Out[36]: (4, 6)
```